# Is it true that httpd looks for .htaccess files in all higher-level directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Given the directory www/html/file.php would it be it be appropriate to place my .htaccess alongside with file.php?

That way making rules for file.php (demo example below)

```
~Rule~ file.php ...
```

file.php would be located.

Comment: Not clear what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It depends on the setting of `AllowOverride` for specific directories - however, in most configurations `AllowOverride` is enabled for the document root.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/de/howto/htaccess.html#page-header

According to that documentation, you should put any rules into the global configuration file instead of .htaccess files if possible. if you can't access the global configuration file, you should put the `.htaccess` file into the folder it applies to.

Comment: ".htaccess files provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis." Ok I see